# Using Comparable Mixin in Binary Search Tree Node Methods

Tags: ruby, binary-search-tree, mixins

I am implementing a Binary Search Tree using Ruby. I implemented a comparable mixin to conveniently compare Node objects within the tree (compares the data attribute), however I am finding a NoMethodError when the "leaf?" method is being called:
`<=>': undefined method 'data' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Here is my implementation:

```
# Node Class
class BstNode

include Comparable

attr_accessor :left
attr_accessor :right
attr_reader :data

def initialize(val)
    @data = val
    @left = nil
    @right = nil
end

def <=>(node)
    return self.data <=> node.data
end

def leaf?
    return self.left == nil && self.right == nil
end

end

# Tree Class
class BstTree

attr_accessor :root

def initialize(arr)
    @root = build_tree(arr)
end

def build_tree(arr)
    arr.each.with_index do |val, i|
        if i == 0
            self.root = BstNode.new(arr[i])
        else
            insert_node(val)
        end
    end
    return self.root
end

def insert_node(val, node = self.root)
    
    curr = node
    left = val < curr.data ? true : false

    if curr.leaf?
        if left
            curr.left = BstNode.new(val)
        else
            curr.right = BstNode.new(val)
        end
    elsif curr.left == nil && left
        curr.left = BstNode.new(val)
    elsif curr.right == nil && !left
        curr.right = BstNode.new(val)
    else
        return left ? insert_node(val, curr.left) : insert_node(val, curr.right)
    end
    return true
end

end

tree = BstTree.new([4])

puts tree.insert_node(6)
puts tree.insert_node(8)
```

Any comments or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You should probably post the whole code, that lead to the error

Comment: Updated, this can be ran and the error reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `Comparable` module implements methods like `<, <=, ==, >, >=, between?` on the object(full list here https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Comparable.html) and all of them are basing their functionality of the `<=>`(space-ship operator).

So when you compare `BstNode` with `nil` like `BstNode.new(8) == nil` the `==` method will call space-ship operator to resolve the comparison. Because your implementation of it tries to call `data` method on whatever is passed, it will try to do so even on the nil (equivalent of calling `nil.data`).

Just add safe navigator(`&.`) to the space-ship like this, and if think you will be good.

```
def <=>(node)
    return self.data <=> node&.data
end
```